# Distance between items in a Listview

Tags: android, view, draw

I have a ListView in my Layout.

```
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_infoitems"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Every list item layout looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_custombutton"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_history_station_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:textColor="@color/rnv_blue_540c"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_history_line_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:textColor="@color/rnv_blue_540c"/>      
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to have a distance between all item. For that I'v played with android:margin property, but without success.

Does anybody know, how to change the distance between item in a listview.

Thank you,

Mur

Comment: Distance between each row? or between each item that appears in a row?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could always set the dividerHeight property. [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:dividerHeight)

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
/>
```

If that isn't what you want to do, in your listview item you could wrap your LinearLayout in a RelativeLayout and add a margin to the LinearLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I had the same idea like your second suggestion, but your first helps me and it's nicer :) Thank you very much

Comment: This worked for me, except that my list is black and the divider was gray.  Make sure to change the divider to the same color as your list!  android:divider="#00000" in my case.

Comment: @NPike, or make the divider transparent with #00000000

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the ListView divider has fragmentation issues. In 2.3 devices, a grey line is implemented by default that doesn't show up on 4.x devices.  This can be addressed by manually setting `android:divider="some_value"`.  I tend to handle all ListView item layout issues within the items layouts themselves.  Its a dirty little trick, but resolves cross version issues.  Note the addition of a "hidden" view below.  This not only fixes the problem between items, but gives you equal padding after the last item in your list.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <View
        android:below="@id/list"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:margin_top="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding or Margin or the ListView itself.

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_infoitems"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5px"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To encrease the distance between the items them self you can use

```
android:dividerHeight="xxdpi"
```

In

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list_infoitems"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="xxdpi"/>
```

Regarts,
Marco